# How to remove double quotes from a CSV file that generated in Access by DoCmd.TransferText acExportDelim

Tags: ms-access, vba, export-to-csv, double-quotes

I am using DoCmd.TransferText in MS Access to convert data from a query to a CSV file but there are double quotes around each field. The csv file will be used by an application and do not accept the format.

I know I can do it manually by Access Export wizard and set "Text Qualifier" to 'None' for removing double-quotes, but I need to do it in VBA. I would really appreciate if anyone can help me to do it with VBA

Here is the codes that I am using:
DoCmd.TransferText acExportDelim, , "tbl_ScrubCSV", "P:\0TPSScrub\" & Instrumentnu & ".csv", False

Expected result should be like:
**E0A,M.V. KULTUS COVE,.,,,CA**

but the CSV file exported like:
"E0A","M.V. KULTUS COVE",".","","","CA"

Comment: I found a workaround and it solved my issue!

Comment: Instead of using DoCmd.TransferText I used Access Export section from External Data/Text File and then changed the name of the exported file from .txt to .csv and in the 'Text Qualifier' used 'None' and finally I saved the export with the name of Export_ScrubCSV and call it from the vba by this command: DoCmd.RunSavedImportExport "Export_ScrubCSV"